# running a shell script with user interaction from java

Tags: java, shell

I'm trying to use a shell script in a java file.

The script runs then prints out the content of a file, and asks the user if its ok to continue

I can start the script off with this and see some output:

```
try {

process = processBuilder.start();

process.getOutputStream();
process.getInputStream();
process.getErrorStream();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String output_line = "";

while ((output_line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output_line);
}
```

but I think when the file is closed it drops out of the while loop.

I was hoping to see "OK to proceed?" but it's just getting stuck on the last line of the file.

is there a way to keep reading from the command line until the script ends?

Comment: Can you please provide your file?

Comment: it is just a simple json file. It seems I am reaching the end of the json file and dropping out of my while loop rather than getting stuck on the last line of the file

Comment: Hmm trying to debug it and it seems that its run the script even before it gets to my while loop

Comment: Sure, after you `.start()` the process runs.

Comment: I had process.inheritIO.start and it was just running it. Now I have process.start and it is parsing the json file while i debug it, but I'm still stuck. I'm trapped in my while loop. It is expecting user input at this point, but I want to be able to parse on the input before sending Yes

Comment: with a bit of debugging, it looks like its stops when it sees the line "read -r -p "Is the FILE correct?..Y/N" _response" in the script file.